# Were the pamphlets shown in the opening scene really published/circulated?

Tags: realism, dunkirk

In the opening scene of *Dunkirk*, while walking through the city the soldiers came across lot of pamphlets/fliers. It had a picture depicting the perimeter which Germans had formed in the sea to surround/trap the entire English/French armies. It had written on it - "We surround you".

Were such fliers/pamphlets really distributed by Germans across the city? Or it was just a way of exposition?
(Nolan has done such things in his past movies. Remember the wormhole explanation from the movie Interstellar?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes & No

Leaflets demanding that the British surrender were dropped from the air, but not of the design used in the film.

[image]

**Left: The pamphlet in Dunkirk. Right: [The real-life pamphlet](http://dunkirk1940.org/index.php?&p=1_245) that inspired it.**

> They were real, but the genuine ones weren’t in living technicolor. Quickly churned out by intelligence officers behind the lines on commandeered newspaper presses, such pamphlets encouraging a surrounded enemy to surrender were used by all sides throughout the war.
>
> <sup>[Slate.com](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2017/07/20/what_s_fact_and_what_s_fiction_in_dunkirk.html)</sup>